# Snowflake on Terraform cloud - The root module does not declare a variable named "SNOWFLAKE_USER" but a value was found in file

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am following this tutorial on how to terraform snowflake.

https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/terraforming_snowflake/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3

I am using terraform cloud and have defined the environment variables using a variable set, but when running the sample terraform code below

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "chanzuckerberg/snowflake"
      version = "0.22.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "snowflake" {
  alias = "sys_admin"
  role  = "SYSADMIN"
}
```

I am seeing the following error.

Warning: Value for undeclared variable
The root module does not declare a variable named "SNOWFLAKE_USER" but a value was found in file "/terraform/terraform.tfvars". If you meant to use this value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.

I'm not sure what is meant by 'add a "variable" block to the configuration", how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you are passing the value of a variable named `SNOWFLAKE_USER` to terraform but you actually have no

```
variable "SNOWFLAKE_USER" { ... }
```

anywhere meaning that terraform cannot use the value / variable and it should be either declared as a variable like above or the value should be removed from the `tfvars` file.

Comment: what if I don't want to have these variables in my code and I want them to be taken from the environment variables?

Comment: @h33 for provider blocks that works, they can just use environment variable, normal modules and resources and the terraform code you write cannot access environment variables. You can set special environment variables of the form TF_VAR_name to map them to a terraform variable but then you would still need a variable definition like above.